# Attaching the DbEntityEntry to Context

Tags: asp.net, orm

i am trying to implement a log system to the entitiy framework context.
i want to get the deleted element primary key when its state is deleted. 
this is my code:

```
if (item.State == EntityState.Added || item.State == EntityState.Deleted) {
    log = new dt_islemLog();
    log.eskiDeger = null;
    log.islem = (item.State == EntityState.Added) ? Enums.GetDBValue(Enums.islemDurum.EKLENDI) : Enums.GetDBValue(Enums.islemDurum.SILINDI);
    log.islemYapanKullanici_id = kullaniciID;
    log.nesneAd = item.Entity.GetType().Name;
    log.oturum_id = oturumID;
    log.zaman = DateTime.Now;
    base.SaveChanges();

    var ID = GetPrimaryKeyValue(item);
    log.nesneID = ID != null ? ID.ToString() : null;

    this.dt_islemLog.Add(log);
}
```

And this is the method that i get the primary key

```
object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry) {
    try {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Attach((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey)entry.Entity);

            var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
            return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;

    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i can't attach the (entry.Entitiy) to context because the cast operation is invalid. How can i get the primary key ?

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs i have found the solution. i have updated the primary key method to like this

```
      object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                this.Set(entry.Entity.GetType()).Attach(entry.Entity);

            var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
            return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;

        }
        catch
        {

            return null;
        }

    }
```